# C# WPF close new user control

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to c#. I have created main windows that I am adding usercontrols to switch between screens with command:

```
Switcher.Switch(new NewPage());
```

The class Switcher is:

```
public static class Switcher
    {
        public static MainWindow pageSwitcher;

        public static void Switch(UserControl newPage)
        {
            pageSwitcher.Navigate(newPage);
        }

        public static void Switch(UserControl newPage, object state)
        {
            pageSwitcher.Navigate(newPage, state);
        }

    }
```

But how to I exit the user control? I wish to finish it (like back button). I can use:

```
Switcher.Switch(new PreviousPage());
```

but it will keep the new page in memory and will not release it.

Example of NewPage class:

```
namespace MyProject.Screens
{

    public partial class NewPage : UserControl
    {
        public NewPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void back_button_Click_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           //what to put here?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The framework does a lot of the heavy lifting for navigation for you, including the "back" operation that you're interested in.

Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750478.aspx

NavigationService.GoBack is what you'll use.

*In the off-chance that you're working on a Windows Store App, let me know, since my answer will be different.*

Answer (score 1):

You should really try and use the standard Navigation services available with WPF. This will give you configurable oage caching and journalling.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms750478(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    private void back_button_Click_(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       Window parentWindow = (Window)this.Parent;
       parentWindow.Close();
    }
```